# How to profile OpenMP bottlenecks

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a loop that has been parallelized by OpenMP, but due to the nature of the task, there are 4 `critical` clauses.

What would be the best way to profile the speed up and find out which of the critical clauses (or maybe non-critical(!) ) take up the most time inside the loop?

I use Ubuntu 10.04 with g++ 4.4.3

Comment: I Modified the original post with additional information

Comment: I did such task with modifying the omp library sources and adding to them an rdtsc's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenMP includes the functions omp_get_wtime() and omp_get_wtick() for measuring timing performance ([docs here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/Runtime-Library-Routines.html#Runtime-Library-Routines)), I would recommend using these.

Otherwise try a profiler. I prefer the google CPU profiler which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/).

There is also the manual way described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) answer.

Answer (score 5):

[Scalasca](http://www.scalasca.org/) is a nice tool for profiling OpenMP (and MPI) codes and analyzing the results.   [Tau](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Research/tau/news.php) is also very nice but much harder to use.  The intel tools, like the [vtune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/),  are also good but very expensive.

Comment: The intel vtune is a very good product. Compared to scalasca or tau the usage is very easy. It is definetly worth the money.

Comment: VTune can actually be used for free for non-commercial software. http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development

Comment: intel seems to have stopped offering vtune for free. There is now only an offering for academic use.

Answer (score 5):

[Arm MAP](https://www.arm.com/products/development-tools/hpc-tools/cross-platform/forge/map) has OpenMP and pthreads profiling - and works without needing to instrument or modify your source code. You can see synchronization issues and where threads are spending time to the source line level. The [OpenMP profiling](https://community.arm.com/tools/b/blog/posts/profiling-openmp-allinea-map-50) blog entry is worth reading.

MAP is widely used for high performance computing as it is also profiles multiprocess applications such as MPI.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [ompP](http://www.karlfuerlinger.com/projects.html#ompp) tool which I have used a number of times in the last ten years. I have found it to be really useful to identify and quantify load imbalance and parallel/serial regions. The web page seems to be down now but I also found it on web archive earlier this year.

edit: updated home directory

Comment: Can't find that tool, and the link is dead. Are you sure about it?

Comment: I also couldn't find it yesterday. As I said I found it on the [internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190906052338/http://www.ompp-tool.com/downloads.html)

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? This is a tool that I have used in the past and was extremely useful!