# OpenMP is not improving the performance

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

So, I believe that the code below, even though I see no errors, is not being able to parallelize my performance and acts as if it is a normal single thread program.

Using `OpenMP` in *C*, I am trying to find the intersections between adjacency lists read from a file. I don't know whether my code is I/O bound, or my directives are not placed correctly, loop is incorrect, the way I am recording time or can it be due to some system requirements? The `omp_set_num_threads()` seems to work fine.

Anything you guys think I should check that may be the problem with `OpenMP`, I would be glad to know. I know it's something related to `OMP` as I have written a similar code in `MPI` that gives the expected performance. Thanks!

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 20000    //number of vertices we are working with
#define EACHLINE 99000  //max chars each line of file could possess

int *allLines[MAX];        //stores all the lines, hopefully
int lengths[MAX];
int lines = 0;

//function for getting intersecton of two arrays
void getIntersections(int *one, int *two, int l1, int l2){   
//arrays and their sizes
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        printf("%d & %d: [ ", *one, *two);
        for(int o=1; o<l1; o++){
            for(int t=1; t<l2; t++){
                if(*(one+o)==*(two+t)){
                     printf("%d ", *(one+o));
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
}

//getting common ones out of the adjacency lists with vertices v1 & v2
void getLists(int v1, int v2){
    int r, s, length1, length2;
    int *arr1, *arr2; 
    int done = 0;
    for(r=0; r<lines; r++){
        if( *(allLines[r]) == v1){
            int *arr11 = malloc(sizeof(int)*lengths[r]);
            length1 = lengths[r];
            arr11 = allLines[r];
            arr1 = arr11;
            if(done>0)
                break;
            done = 1;
        }
        else if( *(allLines[r]) == v2){
            int *arr22 = malloc(sizeof(int)*lengths[r]);
            length2 = lengths[r];
            arr22 = allLines[r];
            arr2 = arr22;
            if(done>0)
                break;
            done = 1;
        }    
    }
    getIntersections(arr1, arr2, length1, length2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //getting number of lines in file
    FILE *tp = fopen("r2.txt","r");
    int ch=0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(tp)) != EOF){
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    fclose(tp);

    FILE* fp;
    if((fp = fopen("r2.txt", "r")) == NULL){        //opens file
        perror("Error opening file!");
        return 1;
    }

    char input[EACHLINE];
    for(int g = 0; g < lines; g++){   //dividing task among processes
        int arr[MAX], length = 0, c, bytesread;

        fgets(input, sizeof(input), fp);
        char* str = input;               //list buffer
        while (sscanf(str, "%d%n", &c, &bytesread) > 0) {  \
        //changing string of spaced numbers to int array
            arr[length++] = c;
            str += bytesread;
        }
        int *rr = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
        for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
            *(rr+i) = arr[i];       
        }
        allLines[g] = rr;
        lengths[g] = length;        
    }       

    clock_t start, end;     //clocks
    double cpu_time_used;   //time recorder
    start = clock();

    omp_set_num_threads(81);
    int r, s;
    #pragma omp parallel private(r, s) shared(lengths, allLines, lines)
    {   
        #pragma omp for
        for(r=0; r<lines; r++){
            for(s=0; s < lengths[r]; s++){  
                if( *(allLines[r]) < *(allLines[r]+s) ){
                    getLists( *(allLines[r]), *(allLines[r]+s) );
                }
            }      
        }
    }
    end = clock();  //timer stop
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
    //time taken
    printf("Time: %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    for(int k=0; k<lines; k++)
        free(allLines[k]);  

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try the approaches suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181078/how-to-profile-openmp-bottlenecks

Comment: How many CPUs does your computer have?

Comment: My computer has two

Comment: @StephenC The critical block is not the problem here though. Even without it, the speed is kind of same as it only handles a small part of the code. It is just there to provide clean ouput.

Comment: So have you profiled the code yet?  As suggested in the Q that I linked to?  Or you just **guessing** where the bottleneck is?

Comment: @StephenC Sorry, I didn't profile it but I am not guessing, I am getting same duration of time printed with and without the critical block.

Comment: If you want to discuss performance in a question on SO, you **must always provide specific numbers** and a [mcve] that **includes necessary input files**.

Comment: @Zulan Thank you! That's what I was doing wrong. And thank you all too that led me to the solution. I had to get this done by the end of this semester. Y'all are incredible!

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic yeah, the link that Zulan mentioned in his comment. I accepted it